# Why does my rectangle not appear? (python 3.8 windows 7)

Tags: python, pygame

I tried to make a clone of a game but the rectangle (which is the basic shape that I will need) does not appear. What did I do wrong or is it just pygame going crazy?

code:

```py
# importing modules
import pygame
import sys
import random

# starting pygame
pygame.init()
# making a screen
(width, height) = (500, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Mincraft')
running = True
# fps counter
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
print(clock)
# geting the x button to work
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.display.update()
pygame.display.quit()
pygame.quit()
exit()
# colors
white = (255, 255, 255)
blue = (0, 0, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (4, 255, 0)

# cube
if running == True:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, blue, (395, 0, 10, 10)),
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, blue, (395, 10, 10, 10)),
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, blue, (395, 20, 10, 10)),
clock.tick(60)
```

and also how am I going to make it empty and 3d? I know I am asking for a lot but I believe someone can explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to draw the scene in the application loop:

```py
# importing modules
import pygame
import sys
import random

# colors
white = (255, 255, 255)
blue = (0, 0, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (4, 255, 0)

# starting pygame
pygame.init()
# making a screen
(width, height) = (500, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Mincraft')
running = True
# fps counter
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
print(clock)
# geting the x button to work
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, blue, (395, 0, 10, 10))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, blue, (395, 10, 10, 10))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, blue, (395, 20, 10, 10))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.display.quit()
pygame.quit()
exit()
```

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- handle the events by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)
- limit frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)